# How do you make a table out of multiple list in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I make table if we have multiple list and that list has within list?

For example if we have

```
List1= [['apple','ball','cat'],['rat','hat','mat']]

List2=[[1,4,5,6],[2,'rat',5,6]]

List3 = [[23,34,54],[12,23]]
```

Please notice each list has same number of list within it however inside list has different number of items.
The result I am looking for looks like this

```
List1    List2   List3
apple    1        23
ball     4        34
cat      5        54
rat      6        12 
hat      2        23
mat      rat
         5
         6
```

Comment: Sorry for really bad format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want..

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest
def lister(l1, l2, l3):
    print('List1   List2   List3')
    for a,b,c in zip_longest(chain(*l1), chain(*l2), chain(*l3), fillvalue=''):
       print('{:7s} {:7s} {:7s}'.format(str(a),str(b),str(c)))
```

Then you just call it.

```
>>> lister(List1, List2, List3)

List1   List2   List3
apple   1       23
ball    4       34
cat     5       54
rat     6       12
hat     2       23
mat     rat
        5
        6
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I was looking for thank you. But I have a problem with this code. if the string is long. for example if instead of apple, it has "appledocasdasdfasasdfasd",  it will mess up the positioning for that line.

Comment: you need to change the 7 to be the length of the longest item

Comment: Ah. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
List1 = [['apple', 'ball', 'cat'], ['rat', 'hat', 'mat']]
List2 = [[1, 4, 5, 6], [2, 'rat', 5, 6]]
List3 = [[23, 34, 54], [12, 23]]


for x, y, z in zip(List1, List2, List3):
  for a, b, c in zip(x, y, z):
    print a, b, c

apple 1 23
ball 4 34
cat 5 54
rat 2 12
hat rat 23


print [(a, b, c) for x, y, z in zip(List1, List2, List3) for a, b, c in zip(x, y, z)]

[('apple', 1, 23), ('ball', 4, 34), ('cat', 5, 54), ('rat', 2, 12), ('hat', 'rat', 23)]
```

Comment: Hello @user3990145 that is something I want but I want those list to be in a line so that it could be read easily. The example I gave above looks bad. Sorry